# Move a game object infinitlly between 2 positions in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im trying to move a game object between 2 public positions (without stop):

i have this code :

```
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, new Vector3(distanciaMinima, 0, 0), velocity * Time.deltaTime);

    if(transform.position.x==distanciaMinima)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, new Vector3(distanciaMaxima, 0, 0), velocity * Time.deltaTime);

    }

    else if(transform.position.x == distanciaMaxima)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, new Vector3(distanciaMinima, 0, 0), velocity * Time.deltaTime);

    }
```

but when its in "DistanciaMinima" it's stopes there .(i think everytime it starts moving towards distanMaxima the code of distanciaMinima executes .)

Any solutions

```
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, new Vector3(distanciaMinima, 0, 0), velocity * Time.deltaTime);

    if(transform.position.x==distanciaMinima)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, new Vector3(distanciaMaxima, 0, 0), velocity * Time.deltaTime);

    }

    else if(transform.position.x == distanciaMaxima)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, new Vector3(distanciaMinima, 0, 0), velocity * Time.deltaTime);

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried Vector3.Lerp?

Comment: So have 2 destinations. When you get approximately to one. Change the destination to the other. Repeat.

Comment: Yes , when you reach one destination you change to the other one and repeat

Comment: You can look at Dotween.

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest way to do this is by combining `Mathf.PingPong` and `Vector3.Lerp`

In the code below, `Mathf.PingPong` will return a value that will increment and decrement between the value 0 and the length, which is 1 in this case.

This combined with `Vector3.Lerp` will make the GameObject continously move from `positionA` towards `positionB` (reaching it when interpolant is 1), and then from `positionB` towards `positionA` (reaching it when interpolant is 0), and so on.

```
public Vector3 positionA;
public Vector3 positionB;
public float speed = 1.0f;

private void Update()
{
   float interpolant = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * speed, 1);
   transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(positionA, positionB, interpolant);
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked using a boolean variable :

Answer (score 0):

thanks , also it works using bool variable "bool movingTowardsMinima=true;" :

if (movingTowardsMinima)
{

```
       transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, new Vector3(distanciaMinima, 0, 0), velocity * Time.deltaTime);

        if (transform.position.x == distanciaMinima)
        {
            StartCoroutine(StopForTime());
            movingTowardsMinima = false;
        }

    }
    else
    {   
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, new Vector3(distanciaMaxima, 0, 0), velocity * Time.deltaTime);

        if (transform.position.x == distanciaMaxima)
        {
            StartCoroutine(StopForTime());
            movingTowardsMinima = true;
        }
    }
```